# Compare means of 2 levels of group_by in one data set in R

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

Take for example the mtcars data set.
I would like to compare the ratio of mpg  of cars that are grouped by cyl only , to the cars that are grouped by both cyl and carb.
Problem is that grouping the dataset using dplyr creates one level of granularity which makes it impossible to compare to a different level of grouping.
So what I did was create 2 new data sets, with each grouping, and then joined them together to compare the 2 means with a mutated column, as below.
This worked, but it just seems like a a roundabout inefficient way to code . What is the proper way to do this?
my code:

```
cyl_only <- mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise(cyl_only_mean= mean(mpg))
cyl_carb <- mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl,carb) %>% 
  summarise(cyl_carb_mean= mean(mpg))
cyl_carb_join <- cyl_only %>% 
  left_join(cyl_carb,by="cyl") 
mtcars_result <- mutate(cyl_carb_join,ratio= cyl_only_mean/cyl_carb_mean)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this without doing the joining by bringing along the summary information needed to calculate a mean.

```
mtcars %>%
    group_by(cyl, carb) %>%
    summarise(sum_mpg = sum(mpg),
              count = n(),
              cyl_carb_mean = mean(mpg)) %>%
    group_by(cyl) %>%
    mutate(cyl_only_mean = sum(sum_mpg) / sum(count),
           ratio = cyl_only_mean/cyl_carb_mean)

    cyl  carb sum_mpg count cyl_carb_mean cyl_only_mean ratio
  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <int>         <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>
1     4     1   138.      5          27.6          26.7 0.967
2     4     2   155.      6          25.9          26.7 1.03 
3     6     1    39.5     2          19.8          19.7 1.00 
4     6     4    79       4          19.8          19.7 1.00 
5     6     6    19.7     1          19.7          19.7 1.00 
6     8     2    68.6     4          17.2          15.1 0.880
7     8     3    48.9     3          16.3          15.1 0.926
8     8     4    78.9     6          13.2          15.1 1.15 
9     8     8    15       1          15            15.1 1.01
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very interesting. Working thru your answer,  It seems as though pipes are unable to continue grouping the original data further after it was already grouped, but when you created new data with the first grouping, a pipe is able to group that new data.

Comment: I used `summarise` for the first operation after grouping. So the original data will "go away" after that. The subsequent operation used `mutate`, which will keep the original data.

Comment: Excellent explanation. However, I will add that now that you introduce the mutate, you do not even need the second  "  group_by(cyl)%>%   "... i was able to replicate the exact same outcome with dropping it!

Comment: This is most likely due to an experimental argument in `summarize` called `.groups`. I would suggest to still include the `group_by(cyl)`, as it may make your code clearer. If you have found my answer helpful, you can [vote/accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).